# C# anonymous tuple list

Tags: c#

Does anyone know of a *shorter* (hopefully more elegant) way to initialize a collection of anonymous types in C# than the following:

```
new[] {
     new[] { "B", "Banana" },
     new[] { "C", "Carrot" },
     new[] { "D", "Durian" },
}.Select(x => new {Value = x[0], Text = x[1] };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single array, like this:

*Warning: Abominable code ahead!*

```
object temp = null;

new object[] {
    "B", "Banana",
    "C", "Carrot",
    "D", "Durian" 
}.Select((v, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? (temp = v) : new { Value = temp, Text = v })
 .Where((v, i) => i % 2 == 1)
 .ToArray() //Important!
```

## Do not do this, *EVER!*

Comment: Haha ok, yeah this is gets rid of the repition, and you could hide the Linq calls in a custom extension method... but the code is still terrible like you say.

Answer (score 1):

You nearly had it..

```
var myCollection = new[]
{
    new { Value = "B", Text = "Banana" },
    new { Value = "C", Text = "Carrot" },
    new { Value = "D", Text = "Durian" }
};
```

Comment: That's not _shorter_.  However, it is the best way to do it.

Comment: I think this is an equivalant alternative (in terms of readability), but I guess I'm trying to get rid of redundant repetition in the code.

Comment: Oh, I see.. I went for more elegant over shorter, missing the question a bit. But stripping out the names of the fields seems like a bit of unnecessary obsfucation to me... imo repetition often isn't bad.